# why changed when i use dirty formz flutter

Tags: flutter

he
when i try to make a change to the input, using dirty with the Formz dependency, and then check out the change and it doesn't work

this input formz
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU5Qn.png)

this when call submit or change value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiMHM.png)

the value if it changes, but  print(state.typeIdLegalFiscal?.value) print nothing,''

why

Comment: screenshot of code is not accepted.